# SwiftUI Drag-and-Drop: 'Reference to member 'first' cannot be resolved without a contextual type'

Tags: swift, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a SwiftUI project with drag-and-drop functionality, and I'm using the UniformTypeIdentifiers framework to handle the data. However, I encountered an issue while trying to access the first item provider from info.itemProviders during the drop operation.

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```swift
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

class ButtonDropDelegate: NSObject, DropDelegate {
    // Your delegate code and properties here...

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        // Check if the drop contains data with the specified UTI (UTType.item)
        if info.hasItemsConforming(to: [UTType.item]) {
            // Load the dragged data as Data
            if let itemProvider = info.itemProviders.first {
                itemProvider.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.item.identifier) { data, error in
                    if let data = data {
                        do {
                            // Unarchive the Data to get the original [Any] array
                            if let keyPathArray = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? [Any] {
                                // Process the keyPathArray here...
                                print("Received keyPathArray:", keyPathArray)
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print("Error unarchiving data:", error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    // Other delegate methods...
}
```

The issue is with the line if let itemProvider = info.itemProviders.first, where Xcode shows the error "Reference to member 'first' cannot be resolved without a contextual type".

I'm using Xcode 13 and targeting iOS 15.0. How can I resolve this error and properly access the first item provider in the drop delegate? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Remember to provide additional details about your project setup, any other related code, and the steps you've tried to resolve the issue to make the question more comprehensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `itemProviders` property in `DropInfo`. Perhaps you confused this with `UIPasteboard`?

Use [`itemProviders(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dropinfo/itemproviders(for:)-93409) to get item providers matching a specified set of `UTType`s:

```
if let itemProvider = info.itemProviders(for: [UTType.item]).first {
```